# raw values or distributions as input to wasserstein_distance - python

Tags: python, distance-metrics

I asked a [question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75237101/empirical-distribution-from-data-python) regarding what kind data I should pass to the [wasserstein_distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance.html) function from the scipy module.

The documentation says that the input data are "**Values observed in the (empirical) distribution**".

My data arrays range between -4 and 8:

```
x = np.array([0.12,-1.29,-3.23,-3.21,-0.13, 1.52, 4.45, 6.45, 5.17, 0.11, 3.48, 5.98, 7.55])
y = np.array([3.54, 2.42,-4.43,-3.76, 0.43, 0.45, 2.56, 7.61, 4.47, 1.36, 2.34, 7.78, 7.13])
```

I initially thought I should create an empirical distribution of `x` and `y`

```
from statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution import ECDF

ecdf_x = ECDF(x)
x_ecdf = ecdf_y.y

ecdf_y = ECDF(y)
y_ecdf = ecdf_y.y

wasserstein_distance(x_ecdf, y_ecdf)
```

But, the answer I got in the link above suggested I just use the actual data without converting `x` and `y` to distributions.

Would you recommend one approach over the other? Are there disadvantages to using the actual data as input to `wasserstein_distance`?

The tutorials I read so far have always mentioned distributions as input data, not raw values. However, as the SO answer from the link above points out, even the examples in the scipy documentation seem to use raw values.

So I'm a little confused how I should go on with this.

Comment: Presumably the function internally creates the distributions. Have you looked inside the code to see if this could be the case?

Comment: I did now, but I'm still not sure. `wasserstein_distance` uses the function [_cdf_distance](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/dde50595862a4f9cede24b5d1c86935c30f1f88a/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py#L9170). There is a section which calculates the CDFs of u and v (lines 9231-9244), can that be?